# RavenDB - Simple way to map mssing (extra) properties in 3.0

Tags: json.net, ravendb

Iam looking for a way to put all properties which arent mapped in the C# object into a generic dictionary and back into the document when written back to raven. But I dont want to make my model depend on RavenDB.Abstraction.

```
class Foo {
   [JsonExtensionData]
   public Dictionary<string, object> Unmapped { get; set; }
}

var foo = new Foo{ Unmapped=new Dictionary<string, object>{{"bar","foo"} }
```

but it should be serialized and deserialized as `{foo:"bar"}`.

In Json.Net there is the above JsonExtensionDataAttribute which do what I want. This attribute is also available in my build of Raven3.0 but it dose not seems to work and I also noticed that this Attribute is not available in RavenDB master (from Today).

What I want to accomplish is to store all data I receive from a source but map only the props I need for now and then later add or remove properties if needed, without changing the data.

So what is the best way to solve this in RavenDB 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

This should work work for you. Make sure that you use the attribute from the Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json namespace

Comment: Yes but I dont want to make that model depend on RavenDB.Abstraction as I wrote above. Cause the Model assembly is used at different places too.